# How to get a for loop into a variable?

Tags: php, email, for-loop, concatenation

So, I have a site where I want to display the results of a test to the user, but I would also like to email those same results to a grader. The code that I have to display the results to the user is as follows:

```
for($i=1; $i<=$totalquest; $i++){
    if($_POST[$i]!=$correct[$i]){
        echo "You answered Question $i incorrectly:<br> $question[$i] <br> You answered: $_POST[$i] <br> The correct answer is: $correct[$i]<p>";
        $score=$score-1;
    }
}
```

This code works beautifully.

The problem comes when I try to create an email message with that info in it.

So far I have this:

```
$message = $_SESSION["firstname"]." ".$_SESSION["lastname"]."'s score is ".$score."/".$totalquest." which equals ".$percent." percent.\r\n\r\n".
"The questions ".$_SESSION["firstname"]." got wrong are as follows:\r\n\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Which works, but I just can't wrap my head around how to get that for loop into the `$message` variable. Essentially I need to concatenate the results from the for loop, create a string and put it into the `$message` variable. But I'm lost!

Comment: So wich results do you want to get into the $message variable? $score? Or some members of the array

Comment: Could you add some example output for what the message should look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `.=` for the `$message`, adding the new message to the old message each time (This also adds line breaks between each question):

```
$message = $_SESSION["firstname"]." ".$_SESSION["lastname"]."'s score is ".$score."/".$totalquest." which equals ".$percent." percent.\r\n\r\n".
"The questions ".$_SESSION["firstname"]." got wrong are as follows:\r\n\r\n";
for($i=1; $i<=$totalquest; $i++){
    if($_POST[$i]!=$correct[$i]){
        $message .= "You answered Question $i incorrectly:<br> $question[$i] <br> You answered: $_POST[$i] <br> The correct answer is: $correct[$i]<p>\r\n";
        echo "You answered Question $i incorrectly:<br> $question[$i] <br> You answered: $_POST[$i] <br> The correct answer is: $correct[$i]<p>";
        $score=$score-1;
    }
}
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$emsg = "";  // email message
for($i=1; $i<=$totalquest; $i++){
    if($_POST[$i]!=$correct[$i])
    {
        $msg = "You answered Question $i incorrectly:<br> $question[$i] <br> You answered: $_POST[$i] <br> The correct answer is: $correct[$i]<p>";
        echo $msg;
        $emsg .= "<br/>\n" . $msg;
        $score=$score-1;
    }
}

$message = (the same stuff you have) . $emsg;
```